# Geometry of 2-D Linear Discriminant Function

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

I am studying ML through the Bishop book myself, and I could not understand why the distance of a given point $\mathbb{x}$ is given by $y(\mathbb{x})/||w||$. Could you help me on deriving this formula from scratch? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try deriving it yourself first, and then ask for help? You just need calculus, and the definition of "distance" between a hyperplane and point.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I agree with you I should do it first. However, what I mean here is I want to know how we can derive that formula by looking at the graph, given I know vectors $w, w_0, x$. I think I'm stuck in the formulating problem, and I'm not familiar with the projection concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H = \{ \mathbf{x} \in\mathbb{R}^n ~|~ \mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{x} = w_0\}$ be a hyperplane (or linear decision surface).
Moreover, the Eucledian distance between a point $\mathbf{q}$ and a point $\mathbf{x}$ on the plane is $$\lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{q}\rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - q_i)^2 }, \mathbf{x} \in H$$

What we want to find is the shortest such distance, which we can do by solving the equivalent minimization problem
\begin{eqnarray}
\min_\mathbf{x} f(\mathbf{x})= \frac{1}{2} \lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{q}\rVert^2,\\\text{s. t.} \\ \mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x} = w_0.
\end{eqnarray}

Using Lagrange multipliers, we can solve this by solving the system:
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \lambda \mathbf{w},\\
\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x} = w_0.
\end{eqnarray}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. It is clearer now. And yes I managed to derive the final result :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the hypeplane is
defined by the equation
$y(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} - w_0=0$.

It holds
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_\perp &=& \alpha \mathbf{w} \\
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} - 
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_\perp &=& \alpha 
\| \mathbf{w} \|^2 \\
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} - w_0  &=& \alpha 
\| \mathbf{w} \|^2
\end{eqnarray*}

The (signed) orthogonal distance
of a general point $\mathbf{x}$ from the decision
surface is given by definition
$$
d(\mathbf{x})
= \alpha \| \mathbf{w} \|
= \frac{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} - w_0}{\| \mathbf{w} \|^2} 
\| \mathbf{w} \|
= \frac{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} - w_0}{\| \mathbf{w} \|} 
= \frac{y(\mathbf{x})}{\| \mathbf{w} \|} 
$$

For the origin, the distance is
thus $- w_0/\| \mathbf{w} \|$.

Comment: May I ask what is $\alpha$ here? I mean for the first equation.

Comment: $\alpha$ is simply a scalar that describes the linear relationship between $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_\perp$ and $\mathbf{w}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!